# moving CALayer with touch moved event

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I tried to move **CALayer** with **touch event**. But there are error messages.

```
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    // get touched point
    CGPoint pt = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self];
    [self.layer convertPoint:pt toLayer:self.layer.superlayer];

    // move piece to the point
    piece.bounds.origin = pt; <- "Expression is not assignable" 
    }
}
```

I have look for solution of this problem, and reached to that this is problem of **strucnt** of Objective-C object. But I couldn't get the solution.

Thanks for your kindness.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, it's not assignable. The same goes for `UIView`s and it's subclasses.

We can't set a `CALayer.bounds.origin` or `CALayer.bounds.size` properties. What we can do, is create a `CGRect` and assign it to `CALayer.bounds` or `CALayer.frame`.

So, something like:

```
// Use frame, not bounds:
piece.frame = CGRectMake(pt.x, pt.y, piece.frame.size.width, piece.frame.size.height); <- "Expression is assignable"
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Because of your advice, `piece` begins moving.